# Print number of records in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

How do you print the number of records in a mysql table?

Comment: Which PHP/MySQL interface? The old one? PDO? ODBC?

Comment: @EboMike print in php idk the difference bettween PDO ODBC I just started messing with mysql...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified from [PHP: mysql_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
if (!mysql_select_db('database_name')) {
    die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());
}
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable');
if (!$result) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
$rowCount = mysql_result($result, 0); // get the count
echo $rowCount; // echo the count

mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Check out the [PHP mysql functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) if you're just getting started.  If you're using any kind of framework, check out the database documentation for that framework.

Answer (score 3):

Use this query to get the number of records in a table (e.g. named "tbl")

```
select count(*) as CountRecords from tbl
```